# What's the difference between the two types of declaration of 'keys' in key value pairs in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays

New to js. I am hardcoding an array of objects in javaScript. the structure of it is something like this

```
const myArray = [
{id:dummy_String_ID1, name: full_name_with_Spaces1, department:department_withSpaces1},
{id:dummy_String_ID2, name: full_name_with_Spaces2, department:department_withSpaces2},
{id:dummy_String_ID3, name: full_name_with_Spaces3, department:department_withSpaces3}
];
```

What confuses me is the  declaration of these keys( id , name, department), I know the values have to be in inverted quotes. But when shall I use the key fields with inverted quotes (like this "id": "12345", "name": "foo bar", "department": "dept 1" ) and when without them (like this id:"1234", name: "foo bar", dept: "dept 1"). What difference does it make?

Comment: They do the same job unless when you have like a space in the variable name e.g, `"My Name": "Full Name"` as opposed to that without spacing `MyName: "Full Name"`

Comment: When having characters not allowed in regular keys, you've to wrap the key in quotes, there's no difference in the resulted object.

Comment: slight correction - only **string** values are in quotes

Answer (score 2):

A key-value pair can be

```
identifier: expression
```

or

```
string_or_number: expression
```

or

```
[expression]: expression
```

where

- `identifier` is a valid variable name or a keyword, like `for` or `if`
- `string_or_number` is a string literal (`"foo"` or `'bar'`) or a number literal (like `123`)
- `expression` is an arbitrary Javascript expression, which includes, but is not limited to, a literal.

Examples:

```
foo: "bar"
foo: "bar"[0] + Math.sin(14)
"hi there": "whats up"  
[300+1]: "hello"
```

Note that this is different from JSON, which only allows string literals as keys.

Answer (score 2):

[JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) requires you to double-quote all keys of an object. JavaScript does not require this. There is no difference between the following two literals:

```
{ prop: 42 }
{ "prop": 42 }
```

But sometimes you want to use a key with characters that are not valid in a JavaScript identifier (leading digits, hyphens, blanks, quotes, colons, etc.), so you must quote the key to become a string which can be used:

```
{ "person:age": 42 }
{ `age-in-years`: 42 }
{ '"quoted prop"': 42 }
```

JavaScript allows double and single quotes as well as backticks. Backticks mark template literals and allow you to interpolate placeholders.

If you need dynamic keys, i.e. the value of the key is computed at runtime, you can surround the key with square brackets:

```
let name = 'computed somewhere else';
let obj = { [name]: 'fancy' }; // will result in {'computed somewhere else': 'fancy'}
```